# the meaning of 'meguri'

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence on a game cover. (I left out unimportant parts)
I am especially wondering about 'meguri' and 'uzumaku'.

Shoujo wo meguri, … tairiku ni jaaku na yabou ga uzumaku.

I have used hours trying to understand it. I read it off a game cover, mostly as kanjies without furigana. I have read what the words are supposed to mean in dictionaries, but the sentence doesn't seem to make sense to me.

My best guess is: Upon the return of this young girl, the continent was swept with evil ambition!

Can someone more acquainted with these words and the jargon help solve this mystery!

Comment: What is your thought? Have you tried a dictionary?  Why did the dictionary leave you unsatisfied?

Comment: Trust me, I have used DICTIONARIES. I read it off a game cover, mostly as kanjies without furigana. I have read what the words are supposed to mean in dictionaries, but the sentence doesn't seem to make sense to me.

My best guess is: Upon the return of this young girl, the continent was swept with evil ambition!

I was hoping someone more acquainted with these words could help solve the mystery!

Comment: Thank you.  Here at JLSE, we consider direct translation attempts off-topic *if there is no evidence of prior research*, which is why I asked.  By including your best guess we will be able to help out out with an answer better tailored to your needs.  Would you mind editing the question to include your guesses?  Also, it may be helpful to see what kanji were specifically used.  If you can, would you mind including those as well?  The more context you include, the better the answers will be.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I have used so many hours trying to understand that game cover that I felt it was valid, but I guess I didn't show it! I will edit the post now. I have literally used hours on each sentence! :-)

Answer (score 6):

巡り【めぐり】 is the masu-stem of the godan verb 巡る, which means "to go around" or, by extension, "to concern". 少女を巡り can be translated as "concerning a girl", "about a girl" or "over a girl", depending on the words used with it. For example, you can use 巡る like so:

> 彼らは座席を巡って争った。
>   They fought *over* a seat.
>
> 3匹の犬を巡る物語
>   a tale *about* three dogs

More examples [here](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%92%E3%82%81%E3%81%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-o-megutte/).

大陸【たいりく】に邪悪【じゃあく】な野望【やぼう】が渦巻く【うずまく】 literally means "on/around the continent, evil ambitions swirl". The meaning of each word should be fairly straightforward as long as you have access to a decent dictionary.

So the whole sentence is basically saying many people all over the continent have evil ambitions concerning this girl. Feel free to rephrase this to make it sound more dramatic in English.

Comment: Thank you!

I still think it is a bit weird sentence ^_^ 

Perhaps when I have read the whole thing I can come back to rephrase it! My thoughts "concerning the girl" go to FFVI and the slave crown. You see, the "shoujo" in the sentence has special powers.